# Webview camera giving an error, creating picture of 0 bytes before taking picture

Tags: java, android, webview, camera

**Those are variables**

```
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    // the same for Android 5.0 methods only
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
```

[image: This is the image error icon]

**This is the file chooser code**
Usually it should create a image after taking the image, but it is creating a blank image before opening the camera intent, and then it is showing an error icon instead of showing the Image.
*Please help me to fix the problem*

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    // create the file where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    // continue only if the file was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                return true;
            }

            // creating image files (Lollipop only)
            private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
                // Create an image file name
                Log.d(TAG, "createImageFile: creating Image");
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File image = File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  // prefix
                        ".jpg",         // suffix
                        storageDir      // directory
                );

                // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
                return image;enter code here
            }
```

**On Activity Result code given below**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // code for all versions except of Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

        } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop

        // start of code for Lollipop only

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    }
```

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile()` Here you create an empty file with 0 bytes. Dont create a file to begin with. You only need a File instance with the right path.

Comment: Can you drop the fixed code please?

Comment: I leave that as exercise to you. You only have to change that statement. One line will do.

Comment: then when will I call createImageFile() function?

Comment: ??? Just call it where you call it now. Only remove line with File.createTempFile and replace by one line of code that builds up a File instance with the same path.

Comment: Can you write the code please?

Answer (score 2):

Remove this

```
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
```

Add this

```
    File image = new File(storageDir.toString()+"/"+imageFileName+".jpg");
    return image;
```

No exercise needed you came here for an answer i presume.

Answer (score 0):

I used both and checked them but non of these lines worked for me.

return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);

File image = new File(storageDir.toString()+"/"+imageFileName+".jpg");
return image;

my code

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
   // File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    File image = new File(storageDir.toString()+"/"+imageFileName+".jpg");

    // Update the file URI using FileProvider
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName()+".fileprovider", image);

    mCM = imageUri.toString();

    return image;
}
```